# Frequency of words in a DataFrame

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe

I've a pandas DataFrame containing a list of words in 'review' column.
I need to find the frequency of the words that occurs in the review column.

```
id  sentiment   review
0   5814_8  1   [stuff, going, moment, mj, 've, started, liste...
1   2381_9  1   [\the, classic, war, worlds\, '', timothy, hin...
2   7759_3  0   [film, starts, manager, nicholas, bell, giving...
3   3630_4  0   [must, assumed, praised, film, \the, greatest,...
4   9495_8  1   [superbly, trashy, wondrously, unpretentious, ...
5   8196_8  1   [dont, know, people, think, bad, movie, got, p...
```

I've tried using counter function but it shows 'unhashable list' as an error.
How to do this??

Comment: frequency of a word in one review or in all reviews ? Give an example how do you expect an output.

Comment: Frequency of a word in all the reviews collectively, like how many times each word occurs in the column 'review' of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you want to have a set of all words mentioned in the column 'review' and get the wordcount over all cells in this column.

Then the solution is as much as one line:

```
import pandas
from collections import Counter
import itertools 

df = pandas.DataFrame({'id': ['5814_8', '2381_9', '7759_3', '3630_4', '9495_8', '8196_8'], 'review':
    [['stuff', 'going', 'moment', 'mj', 've', 'started'],
    ['the', 'classic', 'war', 'worlds', '', 'timothy'],
    ['film', 'starts', 'manager', 'nicholas', 'bell'],
    ['must', 'assumed', 'praised', 'film', 'the'],
    ['superbly', 'trashy', 'wondrously', 'unpretentious'],
    ['dont', 'know', 'people', 'think', 'bad', 'movie', 'got']]})

Counter(itertools.chain(*df['review'].tolist()))
```

Result: 
*Counter({'': 1,
         'assumed': 1,
         'bad': 1,
         'bell': 1,
         'classic': 1,
         'dont': 1,
         'film': 2,
         'going': 1,
         'got': 1,
         'know': 1,
         'manager': 1,
         'mj': 1,
         'moment': 1,
         'movie': 1,
         'must': 1,
         'nicholas': 1,
         'people': 1,
         'praised': 1,
         'started': 1,
         'starts': 1,
         'stuff': 1,
         'superbly': 1,
         'the': 2,
         'think': 1,
         'timothy': 1,
         'trashy': 1,
         'unpretentious': 1,
         've': 1,
         'war': 1,
         'wondrously': 1,
         'worlds': 1})*

Comment: Thanks Viktor, the problem i asked was one of the steps to the solution. Your solution helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension inside counter:

```
Counter([i for s in df.review for i in s])
```